# Как хранить математические выражение в mySql или же в Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle

Есть ли возможность хранить математические выражение в БД mySql или в Oracle.
К примеру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и еще пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как нибудь в виде строки. чего то специального для хранения математических выражений в СУБД нет. Как вы выражение у себя в программе храните в переменных ?

Comment: Нет.Так как я разрабатываю система тестирование для студентов и эти  математические данные (вопросы) они есть в pdf файле с 4 - ответами. Я не буду использовать его как математические операции, только для ввода и вывода в БД и в некий интерфейс html

Comment: тогда храните просто картинками. Если есть желание, то можно перейти на latex и использовать его. А можно использовать [MathML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML).

Comment: В программе, которая формирует комплекты тестов для ЕГЭ это хранится в документе формата MS Word в BLOB-столбце. Т.е. фактически также, как предложил @KOVadim, не нужно писать парсер для latex или чего-то другого. Но там изначально рассчитано сразу для вывода на печать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Родного формата специально для формул в MySQL нет и не предвидится.
За отображение формул должно отвечать Представление, а не уровень хранения.

MySQL может сохранить для вас данные, например, в формате HTML или текст с разметкой LaTeX. А уже браузер или десктопное приложение будет отображать в тексте формулы. Поэтому определяйтесь с другими частями системы. В базе вам будет достаточно типа TEXT или BLOB.

См.

- [wiki Формулы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B)
- [MathMl в HTML5](https://habrahabr.ru/post/250981/)